# cannot find IBM DB2 Express-C for download

Tags: download, db2

I have spent at least one hour trying to find the tar.gz for Linux, for version 11.1 or at least 10.5. All IBM links either don't work or take me to general DB2 pages that have  nothing for Express-C. It's as if IBM is hiding the download links. In the past I have downloaded it several times from URLs that now don't work. I was only able to find the Windows version at a non-IBM site (a version I don't want).

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Did you find what you wanted?

Answer (score 6):

You can find the Express-C download at the below link:

https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pickUrxNew.do?source=swg-db2expressc

Comment: Many thanks. Evidently IBM has decided to distribute Express-C again. When I posted it was officially discontinued.

Comment: Thanks. All public download links had disappeared, as far as I could tell, and I had started migrating away to another RDBMS. I'm not sure for how long we're going to have a free redistributable version of db2...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using cloud based Db2 offerings, at the present date you can choose  only between a docker-image based solution (IBM Db2 Developer Community Edition), or a trial version (90 days) of locally installed Db2.

The docker-image solution is currently V11.1 based and runs on Linux and Mac and Windows provided that the prerequisites are met.

Both offerings are accessible via this link

https://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/db2/trials/

Re Db2 Express-C, it may have been withdrawn from marketing. Study this thread:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=c53df683-6e51-41fa-96ce-0a3d7cfe741f&ps=25

If you have a Passport Advantage contract (for paying customers) you may find additional downloads.

Comment: Thanks for the (sad) news... Are you aware of any other sites that may still have the installer in, perhaps, an older version?

Answer (score 0):

Db2 Developer-C Edition is a non-docker version that can be used for non-production use for free

https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-db2-direct-and-developer-editions

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead. This? https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-db2-direct-and-developer-editions

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Express-C 11.1 in this [link](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pickUrxNew.do?source=swg-db2expressc) **(IBM Account required)**

May be you would find usefull the following urls:

[Pricing](https://www.ibm.com/products/db2-database/pricing)

[Announcements](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/ibm-db2-developer-community-edition)